# Mounting a component which is wrapped in a renderless component does not render

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Let's say I have a component to get some async data:

```
//renderless-component
export {
    render() {
        return this.$scopedSlots.default({
            items: this.items
        })
    }
}
```

Now I have another component, which is wrapped in this component.

```
//concrete-component
<template>
    <renderless-component>
        <div slot-scope="{items}">
            //do some stuff with items
        </div>
    </renderless-component>
</template>
```

Now I want to be able to run assertions on my concrete-component:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ConcreteComponent from './concrete-component'

let wrapper = mount(ConcreteComponent)
```

When I render the mounted component, I expect the slot content to be rendered, however, `wrapper.html()` only returns the string `<renderless-component/>`, instead of the actual html.

How does one go about this?